# Validation rule crashes when fields required are populated in form

Tags: visual-workflow, validation-rule, fields

I have a validation rule to require a Vacancy Announcement No to be filled in mandatory if a Date Vacancy Announcement Opened. I Cloned a ticket and it had the value beforehand in both places. Now I try to submit and I receive an unhandled error due to the validation rule. The value of both is in the form, When I try manually change it, Save it and then I press Submit, it still gives me the error. Here are the pics below.

[image: Validation rule]

[image: Vacancy Announcement No is filled in]

[image: Vacancy ANnouncement date is also filled in per requirement]

[image: Email error from validation rule]

Comment: That isn't a validation rule crashing. Some data update being performed by automation in your org is causing the validation rule to fire. You'll need to investigate the Flow/Process `Submit_HR_Request_Recruitment` to see what it does and why it is failing the Validation Rule.

Comment: When I Clone a ticket that has been closed before, and has all needed fields populated, I create a new cloned record of the old one . Then I try to Close this cloned case but it does not transfer the Resolution field to the new  record. When I fill it in in the screen component, and press Next, the flow deletes all other fields needed to close and it goes in circles. It is interesting why it works like that in LIghtning, but it works fine in Classic.